# SPARQL DBpedia by taxonomic term

Tags: sparql

Have the following working `SPARQL` query that selects items from DBpedia that include the string "fish" in their name.

```
 SELECT ?name, ?kingdom, ?phylum, ?class, ?order, ?family, ?genus, ?species, ?subspecies, ?img, ?abstract
 WHERE {
  ?s dbpedia2:regnum ?hasValue;
    rdfs:label ?name
  FILTER regex( ?name, "fish", "i" )
  FILTER ( langMatches( lang( ?name ), "EN" ))
  ?animal dbpedia2:name ?name;
    foaf:depiction ?img;
    dbpedia2:regnum ?kingdom
  OPTIONAL { ?animal dbpedia2:ordo ?order . }
  OPTIONAL { ?animal dbpedia2:phylum ?phylum . }
  OPTIONAL { ?animal dbpedia2:classis ?class . }
  OPTIONAL { ?animal dbpedia2:familia ?family . }
  OPTIONAL { ?animal dbpedia2:genus ?genus . }
  OPTIONAL { ?animal dbpedia2:species ?species . }
  OPTIONAL { ?animal dbpedia2:subspecies ?subspecies . }
  OPTIONAL {
   FILTER ( langMatches( lang( ?abstract ), "EN" ))
  }
 }
 GROUP BY ?name
 LIMIT 500
```

Here is the [result on SNORQL](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=+SELECT+%3Fname%2C+%3Fkingdom%2C+%3Fphylum%2C+%3Fclass%2C+%3Forder%2C+%3Ffamily%2C+%3Fgenus%2C+%3Fspecies%2C+%3Fsubspecies%2C+%3Fimg%2C+%3Fabstract%0D%0A+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fs+dbpedia2%3Aregnum+%3FhasValue%3B%0D%0A++++rdfs%3Alabel+%3Fname%0D%0A++FILTER+regex%28+%3Fname%2C+%22fish%22%2C+%22i%22+%29%0D%0A++FILTER+%28+langMatches%28+lang%28+%3Fname+%29%2C+%22EN%22+%29%29%0D%0A++%3Fanimal+dbpedia2%3Aname+%3Fname%3B%0D%0A++++foaf%3Adepiction+%3Fimg%3B%0D%0A++++dbpedia2%3Aregnum+%3Fkingdom%0D%0A++OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fanimal+dbpedia2%3Aordo+%3Forder+.+%7D%0D%0A++OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fanimal+dbpedia2%3Aphylum+%3Fphylum+.+%7D%0D%0A++OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fanimal+dbpedia2%3Aclassis+%3Fclass+.+%7D%0D%0A++OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fanimal+dbpedia2%3Afamilia+%3Ffamily+.+%7D%0D%0A++OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fanimal+dbpedia2%3Agenus+%3Fgenus+.+%7D%0D%0A++OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fanimal+dbpedia2%3Aspecies+%3Fspecies+.+%7D%0D%0A++OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fanimal+dbpedia2%3Asubspecies+%3Fsubspecies+.+%7D%0D%0A++OPTIONAL+%7B%0D%0A+++FILTER+%28+langMatches%28+lang%28+%3Fabstract+%29%2C+%22EN%22+%29%29%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0A+%7D%0D%0A+GROUP+BY+%3Fname%0D%0A+LIMIT+500%0D%0A).

This approach finds animals with the word "fish" in their name (example: "starfish" which is not a fish but member of the phylum Echinoderm).

Would like a more precise query that selects DBpedia items by phylum, or by class, or by order, etc.

How to change the query to search only on `dbpedia2:phylum` (Chordata); on `dbpedia2:classis` (Actinopterygii); on `dbpedia2:familia`; etc. ?

Comment: Note that your query isn't actually legal SPARQL (whether or not Virtuoso, the endpoint DBpedia uses, accepts it or not).

Comment: Are the optional statements for filtering the types you need?

Comment: @Artemis yes, so that I can sort results by columns in a spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [Tuna](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Tuna), I see that there is a rdf:type assertion for the class

**http://umbel.org/umbel/rc/Fish**

that looks useful.  E.g.,

```sql
select ?fish { ?fish a <http://umbel.org/umbel/rc/Fish> }
```

[SPARQL results (10,000)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Ffish%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Ffish%20a%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fumbel.org%2Fumbel%2Frc%2FFish%3E%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

There's also the **dbpedia-owl:Fish** class, which gets more results:

```sql
select (count(*) as ?nFish) where {
  ?fish a dbpedia-owl:Fish .
}
```

[SPARQL results (17,420)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%28count%28*%29%20as%20%3FnFish%29%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Ffish%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3AFish%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

While Wikipedia has lots of scientific classification information, I don't see much of it reflected in DBpedia.  E.g,. while the [Wikipedia article for Tuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuna) has kingdom, phylum, class, order, etc., I don't see that data in [the corresponding DBpedia resource](http://dbpedia.org/page/Tuna).

#### Notes

Note that your query, as written, isn't actually legal SPARQL (even if Virtuoso, the SPARQL endpoint that DBpedia uses, accepts it).  You can't have commas between the projection variables.  Also, once you **group by** one variable, the non-group variables can't appear in the variable list.  You could **sample** the other values though.  E.g., you should end up with something like:

```sql
SELECT
  ?name 
  (sample(?kingdom) as ?kingdom_)
  (sample(?phylum) as ?phylum_)
  #-- ...
  (sample(?img) as ?img_)
  (sample(?abstract) as ?abstract_)
WHERE {
  ?s dbpedia2:regnum ?hasValue;
    rdfs:label ?name
  FILTER regex( ?name, "fish", "i" )
  FILTER ( langMatches( lang( ?name ), "EN" ))
  ?animal dbpedia2:name ?name;
    foaf:depiction ?img;
    dbpedia2:regnum ?kingdom
  OPTIONAL { ?animal dbpedia2:ordo ?order . }
  OPTIONAL { ?animal dbpedia2:phylum ?phylum . }
  OPTIONAL { ?animal dbpedia2:classis ?class . }
  OPTIONAL { ?animal dbpedia2:familia ?family . }
  OPTIONAL { ?animal dbpedia2:genus ?genus . }
  OPTIONAL { ?animal dbpedia2:species ?species . }
  OPTIONAL { ?animal dbpedia2:subspecies ?subspecies . }
  OPTIONAL {
   FILTER ( langMatches( lang( ?abstract ), "EN" ))
  }
 }
 GROUP BY ?name
 LIMIT 500
```

Comment: I had done something similar: `SELECT ?property ?hasValue ?isValueOf WHERE {  { <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Fish> ?property ?hasValue } UNION  { ?isValueOf ?property <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Fish> } }` but received incomplete results. While I have not checked yours, my query produced 9,989 results. But I know from a different source that there are 16,033 DBpedia fish items.

Comment: There are 10,001 items in your result.

Comment: @JayGray How do you know that those 16,033 don't include things that are non-fish, like starfish?  How was that list generated?  That's probably what you'd want to use, I guess.

Comment: @JayGray The 9,989 number is surprising.  If you just query for `select ?fish { ?fish a dbpedia-owl:Fish }`, you get ~17,000 (see my update).  That's much closer to your 16,033 number.

Comment: There are approximately 4,450 items uniquely in your version vs. mine. There are approximately 4,000 items uniquely in my version vs. yours. The uniq combination is 14,446 - closer to the assumed total of 16,033.

Comment: The 16,033 is only a count, associated with the DBpedia ontology tree. But I don't have items for the count - just the number.

Comment: @JayGray Can you provide a link?  I'm not sure what you mean by "a count, associated with the DBpedia ontology tree".  Doing `select (count(*) as ?nfish) where { ?fish a dbpedia-owl:Fish }` gets a result ~17,000, which sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: I might be able to combo the queries - but it will only work for fish. I was hoping to use taxonomy terms so I could use the same query structure for other DBpedia biologics. My draft query using `regex` produces the columns I am looking for. But I don't know how to generalize the `regex` using taxonomy terms.

Comment: To get the count I copied results to tables so I could do a `join` to see what was uniq in the two tables.

Comment: Here is the [source of the count](http://wafi.iit.cnr.it/webvis/tmp/dbpedia/realOntology.json)

Comment: I'll work with your updated query to see if I can adapt it to different conditions.

Comment: FYI the `count` equal to ~17,000 is wrong. The actual count of uniq items is ~ 10,000. I copied SPARQL results table to an editors with row numbers.

Comment: @JayGray I think it's more likely that DBpedia only returns a 10,000 results at a time, and that you need to use OFFSET and ORDER BY to get the later results.  E.g., when you do `select ?fish where { ?fish a dbpedia-owl:Fish } ORDER BY ?fish`, the last result is Muraenolepididae, and when you add an offset, e.g., `select ?fish where { ?fish a dbpedia-owl:Fish } ORDER BY ?fish OFFSET 10000
`, the first result is Muraenolepis, and the last is Zvonimir's_blenny.  If you follow that up with `select ?fish where { ?fish a dbpedia-owl:Fish } ORDER BY ?fish OFFSET 20000` you get no results.

Comment: @JayGray So I think that the results you're copying aren't complete.